# Background macro/subroutine which is not shown in the Call Stack

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with lots of sheets and several macros. When I enter VBA and try to write a new Sub into ThisWorkbook module, I see:

> "This will reset your project, proceed anyway?"

assuming, that some project is currently running.

If I press Ctrl + L right after opening the file to check the Call Stack, it just shows nothing.

I did non run any macro myself and there's not a macro, which would handle any event (as far as I checked all sheets and modules in the project) except a little sub for saving event:

```
Workbook_BeforeSave (ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
```

but this one AFAIK should be activated only before saving, thanks to Captain Obvious.

Another mysterious thing with this book is abnormally slow filtering for structured tables, which may be cured by turning off event handler:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

Since both these facts are related to Events, I guess they might be somehow connected to each other.

*Updated to include comments below.*

Well, the problem still exists and I appreciate any idea that may help to locate this pesky macro running totally hidden.

Hm. Anyone with any ideas?

Comment: Pard'n? I don't know any use of Application.EnableEvents, except turning it on and off by True/False commands, so how will it let me know what routine is running? )

Comment: There is a very basic version of a Call Stack in VBE ( CTRL + L ). See if that helps you. Btw. [Here's how to Debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx), and [here how to monitor the Call Stack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263473(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: Well, generally I'm quite accustomed with debugging process, except I didn't know about call stack - bad for me :(
But, what's strange, Call Stack shows nothing..
So, I do the following:
1. Open the file
2. Enter the VBA
3. Try to write a new Sub and get a message, that it will reset my project
4. Press Ctrl + L and get just nothing
5. As a double-check try to write a new sub and again get a message about resetting -_-

Comment: Have you tried toggling a breakpoint, hitting it and then loading the call stack?

Comment: Well, in this case I have in the Call Stack only procedure, which I have run myself. And btw, if I have stop this routine, then I may normally add a new sub, without getting a message about a project reset.

Comment: Ok, sounds perfectly normal to me... What's the question then?

Comment: 1. Open the file 2. Enter the VBA 3. Try to write a new Sub **and get a message, that it will reset my project** 4. Press Ctrl + L and **get just nothing** 5. As a double-check try to write a new sub and **again get a message about resetting**. So why do I get a message about resetting, if there' nothing in the call-stack?

Comment: You get a message about reseting because a macro is running in the background while you're trying to modify the code. It tells you basically that it needs to stop the running macro to allow you to edit the code. The call stack is empty because the macro has stopped by confirming reseting of project.

Comment: So, two points: 1. I did not confirm resetting - I just press Cancel, so "it" (whatever it is) may continue to run while I check it with Call Stack. 2. There is no any obvious macro which may be run in background. It neither exist in any visible module or sheet, nor Call Stack show me anything.

Comment: Well, any other Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One way to reproduce the behavior that you describe is as follows:

1) Have a public variable which is initialized in `Workbook_Open()`
2) Have the option `Notify Before State Loss` enabled (under `Tools/Options/General`)

In this case when you first open the workbook and try to create a sub you see the warning about resetting the project even though no macro is currently running.

If this is the case, a simple fix (if it still bothers you) is to disable `Notify Before State Loss`.

On the other hand, it seems that your project has more general problems. VBA projects can become inexplicably corrupt and this might be the case here. A fix which sometimes works is to export all modules, userforms, etc., delete them, and then reimport them. Rob Bovey (a highly respected VBA guru) has written an add-in called [Code Cleaner](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm) to automate the process. I haven't used it personally but it might be worth a try.